# python os.path.getctime max does not return latest

Tags: python, linux, date

I have two files, one clearly more recent then the other, however max function when sorting by os.path.getctime does not return the most recent file.

```
$ ls -lpat /foo.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 appsc appsc 29653389 May 21 15:05 /foo.tar.gz
$ ls -lpat /bar.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 appsc appsc 29653554 May 27 17:30 /bar.tar.gz
$ date
Wed Jun  4 01:23:29 UTC 2014
$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Nov  6 2013, 12:16:42) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> compare = ['/bar.tar.gz', '/foo.tar.gz']
>>> print(max(compare, key=os.path.getctime))
/foo.tar.gz
>>> print(max(compare, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x)))
/foo.tar.gz
>>>
```

There must be something I am missing there...

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you want getctime() (last metadata change) as opposed to getmtime() (last modification)?

Comment: you are right, getmtime() is what I should have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that ls -t displays the last mtime rather than the last ctime, which is what you're using as the key.  Though mtime and ctime are similar, they are not quite the same -- see [Difference between python - getmtime() and getctime() in unix system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958987/difference-between-python-getmtime-and-getctime-in-unix-system) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'm ashamed of myself. How could I missed that.The worst is that all my code was done using getctime. It only behaved oddly for the first time yesterday after 2 weeks of production.