# Get the last written file from the series of the sub-folders

Tags: python, file

I have tried this solution:
[How to get the latest file in a folder using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-python/39327156#39327156)

The code I tried is:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/**/*.csv') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print (latest_file)
```

I received the output with respect to the Windows log of timestamp for the files.

But I have maintained a log separate for writing files in the respective sub-folder.

When I opened the log I see that the last updated file was not what the Python code has specified.

I was shocked as my complete process was depending upon the last file written.
Kindly, let me know what I can do to get the last updated file through Python

I want to read the file which is updated last, but as windows is not prioritizing the updation of the file Last modified, I am not seeing any other way out.

Does anyone has any other way to look out for it?

Comment: Are you after `os.path.getmtime` (modification time) instead of `getctime` (creation time)?

Comment: Oh... thats what I guess is the solution for the thing... :) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, os.path.getctime() returns the last modified time, but on windows it returns the creation time.  You need to use os.path.getmtime to get the modified time on windows.

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/**/*.csv') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print (latest_file)
```

This code should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

[`os.path.getctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) is the *creation* time of the file - it seems you want [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) which is the *modification* time of the file, so, try:

```
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

and see if that does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have upvoted you. But please forgive me as I want to give a chance to the new contributor this time. I want to accept Tom's answer as an encouragement.