# How to Read Latest Created CSV File?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a few xlsx files created today. How do I get pandas to read the latest one and convert to csv (while keeping the file name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327156
list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

df  = pd.read_excel(latest_file)

df.to_csv(os.path.basename(latest_file).split('.')[0] + '.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

though the answer already been proposed but i would like to add the use of `getmtime`  and `getctime`.

`ctime` changes when the file's ownership or permissions change, as well as when the data in the file changes. `mtime` changes only when the data in the file changes.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import os
>>> import glob
```

### Result:

```
>>> latest_file = max(glob.glob('/home/karn/*.csv'), key=os.path.getmtime)
>>> latest_file
'/home/karn/test_new_2.csv'    
>>> df  = pd.read_csv(latest_file)
>>> df
   10  20  30
0  40  50  60
```

*So, if you looking forward to pick the file which has latest data changes in the file then i'll use `getmtime` over `getctime`.*

*`glob.glob` has a limitation of not matching the files that start with a .*