# Read_Excel for Excel Workbooks with rolling date

Tags: excel, pandas, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some code that begins with pulling data from an Excel workbook that is dropped daily into a folder OR pulled from an email attachment.

The workbook has a naming function like this: `Workbook 20190821` (tomorrow the workbook name will be `Workbook 20190822` I would like to make this process as touch-free as possible so is there a way to channel `pandas.read_excel()` (or some other function) that can handle rolling dates?

Barring some built-in method already available in `Python`, I wonder if a For Loop that increases by business day and then saves as `Path` name would work?

Comment: So you want to write a script that is reading the newest workbook from the folder? Are you aiming to run the script daily with scheduler?

Comment: Yes I would like to write a script (fgos in python) that can read the newest workbook in the folder.  Would aim to run daily, but not sure what you mean by 'scheduler'?

Comment: With scheduler I mean for example windows task scheduler to make the process automatic. :)

Comment: beautiful let me look into this, any noob tips?

Comment: Check this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2Cr_YRQk7o . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script would work for searching today's worksheet from the folder path. 
Is this what you are looking for?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import os

# File folder
file_path = 'your file path for the file'

# Get current date
num = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Current date's workbook name
workbook_name = 'Workbook ' + num

# Complete path
path = os.path.join(file_path, workbook_name)

# Read workbook to Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_name)
```

If you want to find the newest file (if the daily file has not arrived), check this: [How to get the latest file in a folder using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-python)