# How to import the most recent CSV file into Postgres using python?

Tags: python, postgresql, automation

New daily csv file is constantly generated and written into a directory. The task is to automatically import that new csv everyday into the postgres table (so the PG table will be appended with one new record everyday). I have a python script that is good for importing ALL csv files. How can I just import the most recent csv?

```
import glob
import psycopg2

file_names = glob.glob('path/to/directory/*.csv')

con = psycopg2.connect(database="XXXX", user="XXXX", password="XXXX", host="XXXX")

for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_in:
        next(file_in)
        with con.cursor() as cur:
            cur.copy_from(file_in, "tbl_name", columns=('objectid', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'comments'), sep=",")
        con.commit()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is purely to find the latest file in a folder.
If so, there is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder) another thread solving exactly that question