# Python Find Most Recent File Slow

Tags: python, operating-system, max

Am I doing something wrong or is finding the most recent file at a file path location supposed to be fairly slow?

The below code is taking upwards of 3 minutes. Is this expected for parsing thru a list of ~850 files?

I am using a regex pattern to find only .txt files and so after searching thru my file share location it returns a list of ~850 files. This is the list it parses thru to get the max(File) by key=os.path.getctime
I tried sort instead of max and to just grab the top file but that wasn't any faster.

```
import os
import glob

path='C:\Desktop\Test'
fileRegex='*.*txt'
latestFile = get_latest_file(filePath, fileRegex)

def get_latest_file(path,fileRegex):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, fileRegex)
    list_of_files = glob.iglob(fullpath, recursive=True)

    if not list_of_files:               
        latestFile=''   

    latestFile = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    return latestFile
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the latest file in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder)

Comment: @PacketLoss - unfortunately no. that is just pointing me to the code I have but doesn't explain why it would be so slow. ~3minutes to find the latest file

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), this speeded up my file searching massively.