# How to read most recent file with Pandas? Output path is undefined?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, undefined, glob

I'm trying to read the two latest sheets in my folder `READ1` and `READ2` with pandas. Usually when I read files the file name has to be formatted at `'File.xlsx'` but the method I'm using is printing in the terminal as `File.xlsx`. I tried changing the format with:

```
one = [str("'")+str(READ1)+ str("'")]
print(one)
```

Which outputs as `["'None'"]`

My Code:

```
import glob
import os
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter as xl
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np


latest_file = sorted(glob.iglob('C:\My Folder\*'), key=os.path.getmtime) 
READ1 = print(latest_file[0])
READ2 = print(latest_file[1])


File1 = pd.read_excel(READ1,sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)
File2 = pd.read_excel(READ2,sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None)
print(File1)
```

If I run my code as is I get

```
inspect_excel_format assert content_or_path is not None
AssertionError
```

I have tried changing them to csv files too but that doesn't change anything. I think Python is reading it as an undefined variable. Such as:

```
READ1 = [File.xlsx]
```

has the error:

```
NameError: name 'File' is not defined
```

I have been referenceing:
[How to get the latest file in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder)
https://datatofish.com/latest-file-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` method just prints its arguments to the terminal and returns `None`, so `READ1` and `READ2` are `None`.

Replace:

```py
READ1 = print(latest_file[0])
READ2 = print(latest_file[1])
```

with:

```py
READ1 = latest_file[0]
READ2 = latest_file[1]
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I didn't catch the print being an issue. I spent probably an hour on that silly mistake haha