# How to move only new files from remote drive to local when drive is huge?

Tags: python, ubuntu, rsync

I need to find a way to move only new files from a remote folder to my local. Using Python to walk the drive and get timestamps doesn't really work since the drive is too big and there's considerable latency.
I am working on Ubuntu and the remote windows drive is mounted with samba.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: It depends on a cloud folder provider, its abilities, sync protocol, etc. What cloud storage are you talking about?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327156/7887883

Comment: Pavan, the solution proposed is not feasible due to the size of the folders I need to go through.
Andrey, its not really a cloud provider, its just a remote drive accesible through VPN

Answer (score 0):

According to [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) documentation

> Using scandir() instead of listdir() can significantly increase the performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute information

The code below on my machine can scan ~100'000 files over a USB3 cable in 0.4".

```
import os

def files_search(root, time):
    files = []
    stack = [root]
    while stack:
        dirname = stack.pop()
        try:
            with os.scandir(dirname) as it:
                for e in it:
                    if e.stat().st_mtime > time:
                        files.append(e.path)
                    elif e.is_dir(): 
                        stack.append(e.path)
        except PermissionError:
            print(f'WARNING: [WinError 5] Access is denied: {dirname}')
            
    return files
```