# Latest file path is not returned using glob in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to keep a watch on the log folder. If any new file is created then the file path must get returned. for that I have used the following code:

```
import glob
list_of_files_in_real_predicted = glob.iglob(r'logging\real_predicted\*')
latest_file_in_real_predicted = max(list_of_files_in_real_predicted, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file_in_real_predicted)
```

The output returned is: `logging\real_predicted\log935.csv`
instead of: `logging\real_predicted\log0.csv`

Here is the snapshot of the folder and one can see the latest file created;
[image: my folder structure]

Please let me know what I can do to get the latest created file.

Comment: what is showed in the screenshot is the `Date modified`, so you have to use `os.path.getmtime` to get this value.

Comment: I'd suggest to add the output of `os.stat('log0.csv')` and `os.stat('log935.csv)`, since `os.path.getctime` uses `os.stat` underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getctime` is different from `getmtime`. What you're seeing (and the one really useful & widely used) in windows is *modification time*. You want:

```
latest_file_in_real_predicted = max(list_of_files_in_real_predicted, key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Modification time matches the last modification of the contents of the file. Probably why everyone uses it.

`getctime` isn't even the file creation date:

> The ctime indicates the last time the inode was altered

source: [Difference between python - getmtime() and getctime() in unix system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958987/difference-between-python-getmtime-and-getctime-in-unix-system)

Comment: Ok let me check it out. May be this is what I was missing.

Comment: it just cannot be otherwise.